# Is it possible for one CPU to outperform the same CPU at the same Clocks and voltage?

Tags: cpu

I recently had a power outage and my 6700k mark score dropped from 13,500 (98%) to 12,500 (92%) in CPU mark.

Everything was completely clean, no background processes and multiple runs after restarts.

This led me to the question of whether the silicon or CPU package had been damaged in some way and whether or not he same CPU at the same clocks and voltage can perform better.

Comment: Were the tests performed at the same ambient temperature?  As a side note which addresses your question if not your circumstance, be aware that identically-branded CPUs have different "steppings", so performance can vary.

Comment: Same ambients. May you elaborate on steppings?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepping_level